# How do you set the initial state of a checkbox in WPF (either in XAML or code)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have two simple related controls on a form, a `delete` button and a `confirm delete` checkbox.

The idea is to protect against accidental deletions (don't worry, undo will be added later) but still allow the user to delete without annoying confirmations if they so wish.

However, I want the initial state of the checkbox to be set. The XAML code is currently:

```
<CheckBox Margin="0 5 0 0"
          x:Name="chkConfirmDel"
          Checked="chkConfirmDel_Change">
    Confirm delete?
</CheckBox>
```

but I can't see any obvious property for forcing the initial state, either in XAML or in the `Window_Loaded()` code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IsChecked="True"`

Comment: In code will be     CheckBox cb = new CheckBox() ;
cb.IsChecked = true ;

Answer (score 2):

XAML:

```
<!-- Initialized checked -->
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxSwitch" IsChecked="True" Content="Simple switch" />

<!-- Initialized in third state -->
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxSwitch3" Content="3 state switch"
    IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="{x:Null}" />
```

CS:

```
// Two-state CheckBox doesn't require checking null
if (cbxSwitch.IsChecked == true)
{
    // Do something if selected
}

// In three-state CheckBox, IsChecked may be true, false or null
if (cbxSwitch3.IsChecked ?? false)
{
    // Do something only if IsChecked==true (selected)
}
```